# Two connections using Doctrine ODM with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, connection, odm

My problem is that I have configured two document managers like this:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    document_managers:
        video:
            connection: video
            auto_mapping: true
        stats:
            connection: stats
            auto_mapping: true
    connections:
        video:
            server: mongodb://mongo0:27017,mongo1:27017
            options:
                connect: true
                replicaSet: true
                slaveOkay: true
        stats:
            server: mongodb://mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017
            options:
                connect: true
                replicaSet: true
                slaveOkay: true
    default_document_manager: video
    default_connection: video
    default_database: my_database
```

I have the same name for both databases and when I load my page it seems everything's ok (loading my page I only use the 'video' document manager). However, if I use the 'stats' document manager after, symfony seems going crazy.

I have the document managers injected as services like this:

```
stats_service:
    class: %stats_service.class%
    arguments: 
      - @doctrine_mongodb.odm.stats_document_manager
video_service:
    class: %video_service.class%
    arguments: 
      - @doctrine_mongodb.odm.video_document_manager
```

I don't know why, but it seems like every time I do a query, symfony use one of the connections randomly, not the connection of the document manager injected.

Please, help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I have solved my problem finally. I had both replica sets with the same name and all the problems came from there.
To solved I changed the name of one of the replica sets and the attribute "replicaSet" of the configuration:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    document_managers:
        video:
            connection: video
            auto_mapping: true
        stats:
            connection: stats
            auto_mapping: true
    connections:
        video:
            server: mongodb://mongo0:27017,mongo1:27017
            options:
                connect: true
                replicaSet: videoReplicaset
                slaveOkay: true
        stats:
            server: mongodb://mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017
            options:
                connect: true
                replicaSet: statsReplicaset
                slaveOkay: true
    default_document_manager: video
    default_connection: video
    default_database: my_database
```

Answer (score -1):

found an interesting article recommending explicit em setting [here](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/09/symfony2-mongodb-odm-creating-custom-types-with-dependencies/)

Comment: Sorry but I don't see anything about several ODM connections with Doctrine